# how to compile a C program as FDPIC_ELF without using Shared Libs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, elf

my platform:

```
Host:
   | OS: Ubuntu 20 LTS
   | Kernel: Microsoft WSL2 Linux Kernel
   | Cross compile Toolchain: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
   |__

Target:
   | Board: Waveshare CoreH7XXI
   | SOC: stm32h743 (Single Core Cortex M7 @400MHz)
   | Architecture: ARMV7e-M
   | Onboard DRAM: 8MB - 2.9MB(u-boot and kernel) = 5.1MB Free Space
   | Linux Kernel: 5.8.10 (stable 2020-09-17)
   | Busybox: latest stable version
   |__
```

Firstoff, my platform is MMU-less, and MMU-less platforms **cannot** run normal ET_EXEC type elf and the format of the executables should be FDPIC_ELF (an ELF with `ET_DYN` type and should be PICPIE/(Position Independent Code/Executable)).

this is my sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
```

I want to compile it in a way that it won't rely on external shared libraries (e.g. ld-linux.so.3 and libc.so.6), because the kernel loads the whole libraries into ram and they consume a lot of RAM!

How can I compile my program to be an elf with `ET_DYN` type and `PIC/PIE` but without using external shared libs. Note that if I use `-static`, the generated elf cannot be an `ET_DYN` and `PIC/PIE` type. So, what should I do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with the stated restrictions.

`ld-linux.so.3` is the dynamic loader (`ld.so`), which is indeed represented as a dynamic library.

Any `ET_DYN` ELF file needs a dynamic loader — that's why it's a *dynamic* file. The only way not to need a dynamic loader is to have a static file — but then you wouldn't get an `ET_DYN`, but rather an `ET_EXEC`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what about `libc.so.6`? unfortunately when I compile it as `shared`, it needs `libc.so.6`. is there any way to compile it in a way that it won't rely on `libc.so.6`?